# My teacher wrote a triangle on my Japanese homework. What does it mean?

Tags: symbols

One of my Japanese senseis corrected my homework, and several times she drew a triangle next to the item she was correcting. Does this have a special meaning in Japan?

[image: picture of triangle symbol 1]

[image: picture of triangle symbol 2]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In Japan (or Japanese schools), it usually means "Not correct but not completely incorrect, either".

〇 = Correct

△ = In-between "I'll give you half a point!"

☓ = Incorrect

The three symbols are read, respectively, まる、さんかく and ばつ.

Comment: Is it always used for in-between correct/incorrect situations, or is it ever used for non-confrontationally saying "wrong"?

Comment: Hence Japanese Playstation games using Circle for Yes and X for no, unlike US/European games. That was the original intent behind the design of those symbols.

Comment: @coburne: In the role of a teacher, there is no need to avoid confronting a student with a mistake. I've usually seen △ to explain "You may see native speakers use this, but it's technically incorrect".

Comment: What does it mean if the triangle is followed by a number? I have some technical documentation that is full of triangles followed by a number. Example: "When result attribute value is 98, this element is always empty. △２". Example:  "Sets cash in information and cash out information after the normal finish of
deposit transaction. △１".

Comment: To answer my question, the △ in the document I am looking at appears to refer to a document revision number, so it must be the Greek letter Delta, standing for "difference", and it has nothing to do with Japanese at all.

Comment: Please note that △ is used in accountability to denote negative money, or discount for clients. It is also used in trading for change of price is stock.

Answer (score 17):

△ means " almost" or "close" in Japan. 惜しい、もう少しで正解 in Japanese.

Answer (score -10):

Δ is the greek letter for delta. The upper-case letter Δ can be used to denote a change of any changeable quantity. This means the answer is WRONG and needs to be changed.

Comment: [Δ is delta](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%94), but [△ is さんかく](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%96%B3#Japanese). This is comparable to the difference between [口](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%8F%A3%20%23kanji) and [ロ](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%83%AD).