# Difference between 丸 and 輪 for "circle"

Tags: word-choice

Both words mean "circle", although 丸 has also other meanings. But what's the nuance between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**輪【わ】** is closer to *ring* or *loop* rather than *circle*. A 輪 doesn't necessarily be precisely circular, as long as it forms a loop. For example, the Japanese word for rubber band is 輪ゴム; it can deform and have a triangular shape.

**丸【まる】** is a circle typically drawn on a paper, or displayed on a screen (The circle symbol (`○`) is called 丸). The important nuance of 丸 is that it must not have a sharp corner/edge. There's an i-adjective 丸い which refers to any round, cornerless objects. We can even say 丸い三角 (rounded triangle). And [丸 also means 'correct'](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19016/5010).

And one more:

**円【えん】**: circle [as defined in geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle), which is perfectly-round and should be drawn by a compass.

Comment: So 輪 would be something like a "turn"? I.e. something that "runs" a path then connects reaching the starting point?

Comment: Yes, I think that's the important nuance of 輪 (cf. [メビウスの輪](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip))

Comment: 丸い三角 = "rounded _triangle_", right?